# Dependent texture reads on common GLES2 hardware

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, opengl-es-2.0, gpu, glsles

Is there any OpenGL ES 2.0 level hardware where dependent texture reads/dynamic texture lookup will not incur overhead?

[Apple recommends](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/BestPracticesforShaders/BestPracticesforShaders.html) avoiding dynamic texture lookups since it increases the latency of accessing memory when sampling from the texture.

Is this a problem specific to the GPU hardware Apple uses in their devices or is this just a general problem with all OpenGL ES 2.0 level hardware? i.e, how does the **Adreno** GPU family handle dependent texture reads?

Comment: On a related note, I've seen in other places that dependent texture reads should not be a problem on GLES3 hardware, which I suppose is becoming the new "common". (I haven't found an official source for this but have seen it mentioned in various places.)

Answer (score 1):

The A7 and newer 64bit chips do not have dynamic texture lookup overhead, but these are ogles 3.0 devices. The older chips do have the additional overhead.